# why does `this` matter in this case?

Tags: javascript

```js
const library = (function () {
  let myLibrary = [1, 2];

  function get() {
    return this.myLibrary;
  }

  return { myLibrary, get }
})();

console.log(library.get()); // [1, 2]

library.myLibrary = [0];

console.log(library.get()); // [0]
```

```js
const library = (function () {
  let myLibrary = [1, 2];

  function get() {
    return myLibrary;
  }

  return { myLibrary, get }
})();

console.log(library.get()); // [1, 2]

library.myLibrary = [0];

console.log(library.get()); // [1, 2]
```

Only difference between these snippets is this line:

`return this.myLibrary;` vs `return myLibrary;`

First one is mutating the array inside the factory function, but the second one does not. But I do not understand the reason why the first code with `this` is working differently than the second one.

Comment: Because in the first one calling `get` always returns to see what the value of that prop is in the object. In the second it's referring directly to the closed-over `let` variable.

Comment: "*First one is mutating the array inside the factory function*" it's not. You're mutating the property on the returned object - the original `myLibrary` is unchanged. The `get` gives you the state of the returned object. In the second case, the `get` shows you the inner array all the time.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, the `get` function is returning the value of the `myLibrary` **property** on the object created and returned by the anonymous function.

In the second case, the `get` function is returning the value of the `myLibrary` **variable** that it closes over. That variable is completely unrelated to the property on the object, so assigning to it doesn't change the variable that `get` returns. To illustrate that, here's your second example with the `myLibrary` property left off the object being returned:

```js
const library = (function () {
  let myLibrary = [1, 2];

  function get() {
    return myLibrary;
  }

  return { get } // <<================ No `myLibrary` property at all
})();

console.log(library.get()); // [1, 2] <== You still get the value, even though
                            //            the property doesn't exist

library.myLibrary = [0];           // <== Creates a property, which has nothing
                                   //     to do with what `get` returns

console.log(library.get()); // [1, 2] <== Since the property is unrelated,
                            //            there's no difference here
```

If you did:

```
console.log(library.myLibrary);
```

at the end of that, you'd get `[0]`, the value of the property created by `library.myLibrary = [0];`.

Answer (score -3):

Well if your function is not static and myLibrary is global, then you need to use 'this' keyword. This simply refers to non static global variables.